# react and redux, update state from store changes in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to update my `home component`state by getting data from the `redux store` every time the store is updated. I'm not sure what's wrong with the code below. I can't listen to store changes in my `home component.

my dispatch function is handled in this class.

```
export class GanttFilter extends Component {
...
    handleSubmit = () => {
        this.gFilter.filterGanttData(this.formValues)
            .then((result) => {
                if (result.data)
                    this.props.dispatch(ganttActions.loadGanttData(result.data));
            });
    }

...
GanttFilter.propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.IsRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        ganttData: state.gantt.ganttData
    };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GanttFilter);
```

What I would like to do every time dispatch is called and the data changes, is update the state in my `home component`. Here is the component.

```
export class Home extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            data: [],
            links: []
        };
    }

    render() {
          return (
              <div className="fill">
                  <Gantt data={this.state.data} links={this.state.links} />
          </div>
        );
    }
}

Home.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.IsRequired
};
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        data: state.gantt.ganttData
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

the function `mapStateToProps` is never hit when I set a break point. How can I listen to changes to the store from the home component and update state?

Edit: Here is the wrapper component

```
function renderApp() {
  // This code starts up the React app when it runs in a browser. It sets up the routing
  // configuration and injects the app into a DOM element.
  const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0].getAttribute("href");
    ReactDOM.render(
        <ReduxProvider store={store}>
            <AppContainer>
              <BrowserRouter children={routes} basename={baseUrl} />
            </AppContainer>
        </ReduxProvider>,
    document.getElementById("react-app")
  );
}
```

reducers

```
const actionTypes = require('../actions/actionTypes');


const gantt = {
    ganttData: [],
    selectedTask: null
};

export default function ganttReducer(state = gantt, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.loadGanttData:
            return { ...state, ganttData: [...action.ganttData] };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

root reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import gantt from './ganttReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    gantt
});

export default rootReducer;
```

actions

```
const actionTypes = require('./actionTypes');

export function loadGanttData(ganttData) {
    return { type: actionTypes.loadGanttData, ganttData };
}

export function getSelectedTask(ganttTask) {
    return { type: actionTypes.setSelectedTask, ganttTask };
}
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: Can you show what your reducer looks like?

Comment: there are not enough details in the question to be able to provide an answer. what is `result.data`? what is `props.dispatch`? which `mapStateToProps` are you breakpointing? are you seeing any errors in your console?

Comment: @DanO `result.data` is an array of objects. I'm break pointing both, the one under the `home component` doesn't hit the breakpoint, the `gantt filter` is working fine.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense have you made sure `result.data` in `GanttFilter` is not empty?

Comment: @nebuler They're not empty. I can only listen to store changes in `GanttFIlter` but not in `Home` Is threre something wrong with my `connect` function in the `Home` component?

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense It looks fine to me. Can you try logging what `this.props` is in `Home` component's `render` method?

Comment: @nebuler I forgot to pass in the props. i've updated the answer with a screenshot of the error.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense I see your mistake. Don't export `Home`, instead declare it as `class Home extends Component { ... }` (note there is no `export` before `class`). That should fix your issue.

Comment: Alternatively, make sure you use `import Home from '....'` as opposed to `import { Home } from '....'`, otherwise you'd be grabbing the unconnected component.

Comment: @nebuler Thank you! I never would have spotted that. If you would please put that into an answer I would gladly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you import your `Home` component using `import Home from '...'` as opposed to `import { Home } from '...'`, otherwise you'd be grabbing the unconnected component. In general, I would also avoid exporting the unconnected component.

Comment: Can you check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477055/how-can-i-dispatch-function-in-redux

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
render() {
      return (
          <div className="fill">
              <Gantt data={this.state.data} links={this.state.links} />
      </div>
    );
}
```

To

```
render() {
      return (
          <div className="fill">
              <Gantt data={this.props.data} links={this.state.links} />
      </div>
    );
}
```

Your data is comming from your props (redux), not from your state.

Comment: Can you check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477055/how-can-i-dispatch-function-in-redux